# How to create New custom button of Quote for create New Quote Using URL Hack

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, commandbutton, urlhacking

I am going to provide one custom button to my visualforce page for create new Quote, Quote is Standard object..

Visualforce page :

`<apex:commandButton value="Create New Quote" action="/0Q0/e?retURL=%2F0063600000D5oyOAAR&oppid=0063600000D5oyO"/>`

Now, question is How can i pass Blank (selectable lookup) when i click on this New Button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not leave Opportunity as a blank just because of both object have Master-Detail Relationship.

Alternate solution is :

Create one Visualforce and set that page in your new Custom button action

`<apex:commandbutton Value='Create New Quote' action='/apex/yourpageName' />`